# Displaying planet in OpenMapTiles not working, but Spain works

Tags: server, openmaptiles

I'm setting up an OpenMapTiles-server-dev to work in Docker container and as a map source i downloaded and configured planet. The map is not showing up in view and also in main UI.

My source of OMT-Server, also tried other servers:

```
docker pull klokantech/openmaptiles-server
```

I grant all permissions, give more resoursces to Docker, installed Node.js etc. The best part is that i run another map source like Spain or Switzeland and it works like a charm.

PowerShell commands:

```
 docker run -it -v D:\spain:/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl
```

```
 docker run -it -v D:\planet:/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl
```

Output of both maps are identical after executing ^commands

So the both maps(planet, Spain) was configured succesfuly, but only Spain works properly. Also using another PC with normal Windows 10 I was able to display properly planet map.

Answer (score 0):

[SLOVED]
I just installed Windows 10 edu for testing and it works fine. So if you have similar problem just have in mind that Windows 2019 server is not compatible to run larger maps.